# How can i configure reverse proxy with nginx with Subdomains

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I need some help.

let me show my case.

I have 1 nginx with one external domain

testeapps.com

and i need to put any subdomais with proxy pass after the .com

For example.

testeapps.com/api
proxy_pass -> https://192.168.100.1/api

testeapps.com/strad
proxy_pass -> https://192.168.100.2/strad

In all case
i need to foward the one external URL to any internal server after /.

Someone help me?

I´ve tried with some docs.
but unsuccess.